# Acer Aspire One a0531h/zg8 BIOS suddenly asks for password

Tags: bios, password-recovery, acer-aspire-one

I have an old Acer Aspire One a0531h/zg8 with Arch Linux installed on it. I think it had Windows 7 before. I've never had any problems with it after I started using Arch. However, recently, I turned the computer on and the BIOS asked for a password. I don't understand why; I have never in my life set a BIOS password on any device.

Acer customer support told me I could send my computer in to have the password removed (for a fee, because it isn't covered under the warranty). I *really* don't want to have to pay to get it removed.

**Things I tried:**

- I know about entering the wrong password on purpose to get the error code, but I don't receive one. I get a box saying "System will halt!" every time.
- Flashing BIOS from a FAT formatted ~1gb USB stick with the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> combination. I downloaded compatible BIOS versions only, renamed files appropriately, and followed all instructions exactly as given. The power light and USB stick light will blink for maybe 30 seconds until the computer restarts as usual and asks for a password like nothing ever happened.
- Unscrewing the bottom panel and removing the keyboard so I could open the front of the computer. I looked there, and on the bottom, for the CMOS battery but I couldn't find it. I had an incredibly difficult time opening this computer up... the CMOS route is the least preferred. It's fine if that is the best solution, but I need really clear directions on where everything is. I'm really dull when it comes to the physical aspect of computers.

Is there a way to either get the error code or get flashing to work? Is there something I haven't tried that could remove the password?

Thank you! If more information is needed, let me know.